# wp_delete_post() not working with BBpress replies

Tags: bbpress

I'm trying to auto-delete all BBpress replies of a user when someone's account is banned, but the wp_delete_post is not working with replies.

wp_delete_posts() returns a post object if it runs successfully, and it does do this with the reply, but the reply is not deleted from its respective topic!

```
$args = array (
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => array('topic','reply'),
        'author' => $user_id
);
$user_posts = new WP_Query($args);
while ( $user_posts->have_posts() ) : $user_posts->the_post();
    wp_delete_post(get_the_ID(), true);    
endwhile;
```

Comment: How the above functionality is related with user account getting banned? Whats the hook you are using?

Comment: The rest of the function works fine, this is the only problematic part. But just FYI I have a front-end button that my mods can click that deletes a user account via AJAX. I was adding this to that function bc deleting a user does not delete their replies (which may also be because of this bug!)

Comment: The above code works for me. 

wp_delete_posts() never returns a post object if it runs successfully rather its a wpdb object. 

Also can you please make it clear "it does do this with the reply" - do you mean delete here? 

Also do you have nested replies?

Comment: It does return the wpdb object with replies, yes, but the replies still show and are even editable. Yes I do have threaded replies. Is that an issue?